# Reactivations in a month

Tags: snowflake-schema

I need to find the users who have reactivated for a month. The number of users who were  invoiced previously, then stopped being invoiced and then started being invoiced again in the month. Below query gives me the desired result for one month.

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USERID)
    FROM (
        SELECT USERID
        ,MIN(DATE ( INVOICE_DT)) AS ADD_ON_GA_DATE
        FROM INVOICE_D AS ID
        WHERE 
        USERID IN (
                    (
                    SELECT USERID
                    FROM INVOICE_D AS ID
                    WHERE INVOICE_AMT > 0
                    AND LAST_DAY(INVOICE_DT) = ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE - 1), - 1)
                    GROUP BY USERID
                    ) 
                    MINUS
                   (SELECT USERID
                    FROM INVOICE_D AS ID
                    WHERE LAST_DAY(INVOICE_DT)  = ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE - 1), - 2) 
                    GROUP BY USERID)
                  )
        GROUP BY USERID
        ) AS TOTAL_POP
    WHERE LAST_DAY(ADD_ON_GA_DATE) != ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE - 1), - 1)
   ;
```

I want this query to calculate for all months except current month(excluding September 2020). This gives me data for all months, wherein users where active in current month and not in previous month. Now from this list i want to only those users who are active in all older months too along with current month. Not sure where I need to add the filter for excluding the current month.

```
WITH MONTH_SUMMARY AS 
(
  SELECT USERID
  ,TO_CHAR(INVOICE_DT,'YYYY-MM') "INVOICE_MONTH"
  ,TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(INVOICE_DT,-1),'YYYY-MM') "PREV_MONTH"
  ,SUM(INVOICE_AMT) "MONTHLY_TOTAL"
  FROM INVOICE_DATA
  WHERE INVOICE_DT >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(current_date(),-13),'MONTH') 
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
),

USER_DATA AS 
  (
  SELECT USERID, INVOICE_MONTH, MONTHLY_TOTAL
  FROM MONTH_SUMMARY MS_THIS
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT USERID
    FROM MONTH_SUMMARY MS_NEXT
    WHERE 
      MS_THIS.USERID = MS_NEXT.USERID AND
      MS_THIS.NEXT_MONTH = MS_NEXT.INVOICE_MONTH
   )
   AND MS_THIS.INVOICE_MONTH < TO_CHAR(current_date(),'YYYY-MM') 
)
SELECT INVOICE_MONTH, COUNT(DISTINCT USERID) "USER_COUNT"
FROM USER_DATA
GROUP BY INVOICE_MONTH
ORDER BY INVOICE_MONTH
 ;
```

Comment: Just to clarify the reinstatement logic... for a given month a reinstatement is any user who has been invoiced in that month but was not invoiced in the previous month but was invoiced in a month prior to that? Can the previous invoice be in any month in the past, in the last 12 months or some other period?

Comment: When you say "only those users who are active in all older months" do you mean since you started recording data, or in the last 12 months, or something else?

Comment: Not just twelve months all previous Months excluding the the current month -1

Answer (score 0):

This SQL should probably get you close to what you want:

```
-- Create a CTE that holds monthly summaries per user; adjust as necessary to hold the data required in the final output
-- Last day of month used, rather than just the month, to make subsequent date logic easier
WITH MONTHLY_SUMMARY AS (
    SELECT USERID,
            LAST_DAY(INVOICE_DT) AS INVOICE_MONTH,
            SUM(INVOICE_AMT) MONTHLY_AMT
    FROM INVOICE_D    
    GROUP BY 1,2
    HAVING MONTHLY_AMT > 0 -- Only include user/month combinations that have an invoice amount. Only required if zero-value invoices exists. Would need adjusting if +ve and -ve amounts exist that could sum to zero

)
--Main select
SELECT THIS_MONTH.INVOICE_MONTH, THIS_MONTH.USERID, THIS_MONTH.MONTHLY_AMT
FROM MONTHLY_SUMMARY THIS_MONTH
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( -- exclude records where there is an invoice amount for the same user in the previous month
    SELECT 1 FROM MONTHLY_SUMMARY LAST_MONTH
    WHERE THIS_MONTH.USERID = LAST_MONTH.USERID
    AND ADD_MONTHS(THIS_MONTH.INVOICE_MONTH,-1) = LAST_MONTH.INVOICE_MONTH
)
AND EXISTS ( -- include records where there is an invoice amount for the same user in month 2, or more, priior to this month
    SELECT 1 FROM MONTHLY_SUMMARY LAST_MONTH
    WHERE THIS_MONTH.USERID = LAST_MONTH.USERID
    AND LAST_MONTH.INVOICE_MONTH <= ADD_MONTHS(THIS_MONTH.INVOICE_MONTH,-2) 
)
AND LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) > THIS_MONTH.INVOICE_MONTH -- EXCLUDE THE CURRENT MONTH
AND THIS_MONTH.INVOICE_MONTH <> (SELECT MIN(INVOICE_MONTH) FROM MONTHLY_SUMMARY) -- Exclude 1st month in dataset
ORDER BY THIS_MONTH.INVOICE_MONTH, THIS_MONTH.USERID
;
```

Comment: Thank you will check on this.. Thank you so much